# android custom list adapter to remember databse id

Tags: android

How do I create a list adapter that remember the id as well as the content?

I want to make it in a way that when I initialize the adapter, I will feed it a map with id as the key and the content as the value, as opposed to just a list of strings.

What do I have to subclass, and what I put for the constructor?

Comment: do you want to remember the whole content of list or just selected item?

Comment: by content I just mean the one of the column from a table, just a string in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that with sharePreferneces. It tried it works fine for me.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putInt(key,value);
prefsEditor.commit();
```